# RewriteRule redirecting to index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework, redirect

This is something weird.

In a website that I'm working on, which uses Zend framework, there was a requirement to redirect any URLs ending with "/" (e.g., http://test.com/test-url/) to the same URL without the "/" (e.g., http://test.com/test-url).

I added this to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$     /$1 [R=301,L]
```

For many URLs this is working fine. But for URLs like http://test.com/index/test-url/ this gets redirected to http://test.com/index.php/test-url, which is undesired. Can somebody throw some light on why this happens please?

I know you can complain about the unfriendly URLs like "/index/test", but I need to live with it for now :)

The requirement was to avoid these being seen as duplicate URLs by search bots, which affects SEO as some believe.

Here is the complete .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$     /$1 [R=301,L]

# Some other strange redirections
RewriteRule ^index/$ / [R=301]
RewriteRule ^css/$ / [R=301]
RewriteRule ^js/$ / [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

# compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-eruby
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete .htaccess file?

Comment: @Sumurai8 added in the question

Comment: Note that RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L] is required for Zend front controller

Comment: Probably unrelated as you would otherwise get an internal server error, but AddOutputFilterByType is part of mod_filter and not part of mod_deflate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour seems to surface when you have the MultiViews option turned on. Multiviews allows for content negotiation with mod_negotiation. You can turn it off by adding the following in the very top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

For more information, see [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) and some more information about [content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html).

Alternatively you can rename index.php to prettybutterflies.php and change your RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule ^ prettybutterflies.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: (please note that since you are using permanent redirects, you might need to clear your cache)

Comment: thats magic and it works! many thanks. But my little mind cannot decipher how MultiViews can affect this.

Comment: The server reads index in the url. It sees a file index.php in the folder. I believe it looks at what the client wants to receive, and checks what index.php would return. It determines that index.php is indeed the way to go and rewrites it to index.php and uses whatever is behind the `/` as path info. Then mod_rewrite kicks in and works on this new url.